# Calling the function 'list(...)' directly on a created class

Tags: python, list

I am aware that within the Python Class creation one could overload some specific functionalities, so that when some of Python's built-in functions are called on the created object they are able to act properly on them ie.

```
class Node(object):    
    def __init__(self, contents=None,leftNode=None, rightNode=None):
        super(Node, self).__init__()
        self.__leftNode = leftNode
        self.__rightNode= rightNode
        self.__contents = contents

    # OverLoad the str function. Prints the address of the Node, and it's contents.
    def __str__(self):  
        addr=repr(self).split(' ')[-1][:-1]
        return str('Addr: {0}\tContents: {1}'.format(addr, self.__contents))
```

This allows pretty printing of the data that is output when print or str(...) is called on the node object. What I would like to know is if there is a way to do the same for list(...) where in, if I were to pass a Linked List object that was implemented, it would be able to return a python list implementation, which would just append all of the nodes contents to a list, and return it.

I know this sounds somewhat simple, and unneeded, but about to produce a Binary Tree Class implementation, and would like to be able to produce a Heap Sort Able list in itself. I tried to implement the **iter** property, but just went about creating a weird infinite loop.

### Edit

Link to full Implementation of the LinkedListData Type: [Linked List Gist](https://gist.github.com/LuisPerez64/010e83cb51ceea5d91568a06b1235222).

Main difference between itself, and Pythons Linked List is easier appending to whichever side of the list would be wanted, and ability to enable type safety, which can be turned on by indicating the type within the list from the beginning. Added implementation cues supplied by @Leva7.
As this was my first "Pure" Data Structure, any tips on best practices, sans DocStrings became familiar with those a bit more, would be appreciated, and welcome, also inefficiencies within the code base as well.

Comment: Why not create a getList() function instead? Why does it have to work with built-in list() call?

Comment: Attempting to learn the ins and outs of the class constructs within python, and, I've implemented a function for it, just want to make the object more integrateable within the Python Structure, without using as much of the pythonic built ins as possible. Attempting to treat the language as basely as possible is the short and curly of this.

Comment: Should I maybe move the link to the implementation to the answer? As I said, question body is made solely for the question. Also, it's better not to ask for code improvements on Stack Overflow, others might consider the post off-topic. Such questions belong to another Stack Exchage site - Code Review. It may be a good idea to post your code there to get helpful tips regarding efficiency and code style

Comment: Yeah, I'll remove it from the Answer, saw that I could have appended it to the end of the question when I scrolled all the way down, will leave the Question, and the Gist Note.

Comment: Side note: if you have an addendum to a question (such as a related question or an update that cannot easily be merged discreetly into the original) then please put it at the end, not the beginning. It is useful for new readers who do not see the first state of the question to be able to read it in chronological order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done by implementing the `__iter__` method. The list constructor will use it to iterate over your object and create a list from that. Keep in mind that it should be a generator method, rather than returning a list.

Example:

```
class Test:
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(5):
            yield i

ls = list(Test())
print(ls)
```

The output will be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In your case, you would take the first node, and until the end (which is somehow marked in your implementation) you yield the next node, so something like that:

```
def __iter__(self):
    curr_node = self
    while curr_node.__not_last:
        yield curr_node.__contents
        curr_node = curr_node.__rightNode
```

And for that you need a `__not_last` boolean property in the `Node` object

For future reference, [here](https://gist.github.com/LuisPerez64/010e83cb51ceea5d91568a06b1235222) is the OP's full linked list implementation

Comment: Had not seen the yield function within an iterator as of yet. This is exactly what I need. Even better actually, since It allows me to only use base data types within my object itself.

Comment: The iteration within the Linked List implementation of the Node, iterates internally based on the C Construct of an ending Null Pointer. But that example in itself addresses that. Kind of wish I'd figured a bit more of it out myself. Looking into yield more at this very moment.

Comment: @L.P. So if the node is the last one, the `__rightNode` property is `None`? Even better, then the check is simply `while curr_node.__rightNode`. But you probably already did it :)

Comment: Yep. Adding the implementation to the Question, as I don't think it's possible to do it in a comment.

Comment: @L.P. actually, I don't think it's a good idea. Questions should only contain questions, and if you want, I can include the implementation in the answer (crediting you, of course)

Comment: @L.P. Also, if you want to provide a full implementation, it might be a good idea to also include the new methods that you've defined for it

Comment: Added a link to the Gist containing the implementation. If you have time/tips with regards to the proper manner of going about anything in it. It would be appreciated as well. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Feel free to add to your answer. Keeps the structure of the question cleaner that way as well.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a good answer, but its only part of the story so I thought I'd type out the long-winded version. You are interested in python's [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) which is implemented by two methods: `__iter__()` and `__next__()`. The protocol is simple: `__iter__` returns some object with a `__next__` method and repeated calls to `__next__` return values until finally `StopIteration` is raised. Objects with `__iter__` are *iterable* while objects with `__next__` are *iterators*.

Implementors have several choices on how to implement an iterable. In this case, `A` is its own iterator.

```
class A:
    """A class that is its own iterator"""
    def __iter__(self):
        # ....
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        # ...
        return next_value
```

This is a common strategy when you want all iterators of an object to see the same thing. A file object is a good example:

```
>>> f is f.__iter__()
True
```

Here, there is only one backing file with one file pointer and all iterators use it. This is why nested `for` loops work for files, for example. Its also the source of many errors. Its common for people to put a `__next__` on an object (because that's what examples tend to show) only to find their code breaks when there are 2 iterators on that object.

```
with open('foo') as foo:
    next(foo) # advance iterator to get rid of line
    for line in foo:
        if line.startswith('begin token'):
            for line in foo: # second iterator gets same view
                if line.startswith('end token'):
                    break
```

In this case, `B` creates a separate object to do the iteration:

```
class BIter:
    """A iterator for another class"""
    def __init__(self, b_obj):
        self.b_obj = b_obj

    def __next__(self):
        ...
        return next_value

class B:
    """A class that uses another iterator class"""
    def __iter__(self):
        return BIter(self)
```

A list object is a good example, all iterators of the list are independent:

```
>>> l is l.__iter__()
False
>>> next(l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator
```

Finally, you can let python create the iterator for you with generator expression (that is, a function that `yield`s) or any other function that returns an iterator.

```
class C:
    """A class that uses a generator to let python build the iterator
    class for it.
    """
    def __iter__(self):
        for x in whatever:
            yield x
```

Comment: Ran into something somewhat similar to this with some class wide "static" variables, and also on my first meeting with the next() function, which I did not know would cause one of my iterators to become an inaccessible, at that point thought to be anyways, StopIteration exception pit. Continued reading into generators, and iterators as well, this helped clear a few misunderstandings in itself http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html